# optimisation and parallelisation of the for loop

Tags: r, database, for-loop, dataframe, parallel-processing

I got some problem with my code. First of all,i it's, I think, a double code, as one is a set of the functions, which are used for the main code which is a nested for loop, smth like this:

```
hijos <- function(con, clasification, element){
  example <- sprintf("(select hcodniv2 from (select pcodniv1, hcodniv1, pcodniv2, hcodniv2, level from stock.clasificaciones where pcodniv1=%d and hcodniv1=pcodniv1 start with pcodniv2=%d connect by prior hcodniv2=pcodniv2)) minus (select pcodniv2 from (select pcodniv1, hcodniv1, pcodniv2, hcodniv2, level from stock.clasificaciones where pcodniv1=%d and hcodniv1=pcodniv1 start with pcodniv2=%d connect by prior hcodniv2=pcodniv2))", clasification, element, clasification, element)
  codhijos <- dbSendQuery(con, example)
  hijos_df <- fetch(codhijos, n=-1)
  if (length(hijos_df$HCODNIV2) == 0) {
    hijos_df <- data.frame("HCODNIV2" = element)
  }
  dbClearResult(codhijos)
  hijos_df
}

hijos_string <- function(con, clasification, element) {
  df1 <- hijos(con, clasification, element)
  df1 <- paste(df1$HCODNIV2,collapse=",")
  df1
}


resultado <- function(datos_inversion, classProduct, classBranch, year, product, branch, df1, df2) {
year_1 = year - 1
df5 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 76 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s)",classProduct, classBranch, year_1, df1, df2))
df4 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 54 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s)",classProduct, classBranch, year_1, df1, df2))
df3 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 54 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s)",classProduct, classBranch, year, df1, df2))
df2 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 76 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s)",classProduct, classBranch, year, df1, df2))
df7 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 54 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 = %d and CODNIV5= %d",classProduct, classBranch, year, product, branch))
df6 <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from datos_inversion where CODUNIDAD = 54 and CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and ANYO = %d and CODNIV3 = %d and CODNIV5= %d",classProduct, classBranch,  year_1, product, branch))
colnames(df5)[1] <- 'VALOR_IR14'
colnames(df4)[1] <- 'VALOR_IN14'
colnames(df3)[1] <- 'VALOR_IN15'
colnames(df2)[1] <- 'VALOR_IR15'
colnames(df6)[1] <- 'VALOR_IN14_tot'
colnames(df7)[1] <- 'VALOR_IN15_tot'
colnames(df5)[3] <- 'CODUNIDAD_IR'
colnames(df2)[3] <- 'CODUNIDAD_IR'
colnames(df3)[3] <- 'CODUNIDAD_IN'
colnames(df4)[3] <- 'CODUNIDAD_IN'
df6 <- cbind(df6, df7[!names(df7) %in% names(df6)])
df5 <- cbind(df5, df2[!names(df2) %in% names(df5)])
df4 <- cbind(df4, df3[!names(df3) %in% names(df4)])
newdf <- cbind(df5, df4[!names(df4) %in% names(df5)])
newdf$RES1p = log(newdf$VALOR_IR14)
newdf$RES1p_15 = log(newdf$VALOR_IR15)
newdf$Res1p_tot = newdf$RES1p_15 - newdf$RES1p
newdf$Res2p = newdf$VALOR_IN14/ df6$VALOR_IN14
newdf$Res2p_15 = newdf$VALOR_IN15/ df6$VALOR_IN15
newdf$Res2p_tot = (newdf$Res2p + newdf$Res2p_15)/ 2
newdf$RESULTADO = newdf$Res1p_tot * newdf$Res2p_tot
df_resultados = sum(newdf$RESULTADO, na.rm = TRUE)
data_frame <- data.frame("ANYO" = year, "RESULTADO" = df_resultados, "PRODUCTO" = product, "RAMA" = branch, "CLASE_PR" = classProduct, "CLASE_R" = classBranch) 
data_frame
}
```

These functions are just making calculations from the data from the data frame from the Oracle.

The code itself this one:

```
x = 1965:2015
d = 2000
g = 1000
y = c(2026,2017,2019,2023)
z = c(1034,1002,1056,1057)
start <- proc.time() # Start clock
dat <- data.frame()
for (year in x) {
  for (classProduct in d){
   for (product in y) {
      prod_string <- hijos_string(con, classProduct, product)
  product_df <- c(product, prod_string)
  product_df <- paste(product_df, collapse = ",")
  for (classBranch in g){
    for (branch in z) {
      branch_string <- hijos_string(con, classBranch, branch)
      branch_df <- c(branch, branch_string)
      branch_df <- paste(branch_df, collapse = ",")

      consulta <- sprintf("select * from stock.V_CALCULOS where  CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s) order by codniv1, codniv2, codniv3, codniv4, codniv5, codlugar, codunidad, anyo",classProduct, classBranch, product_df, branch_df)
      resuni <- dbSendQuery(con, consulta)
      datos_inversion <- fetch(resuni, n=-1)
      dbClearResult(resuni)

      df<-resultado(datos_inversion, classProduct, classBranch, year, product, branch, prod_string, branch_string)
      dat <- rbind(dat, df)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  
print(dat)
time_elapsed_parallel <- proc.time() - start # End clock
time_elapsed_parallel

dbDisconnect(con)
```

1. So, my problem is.. I need somehow to parallelize this code to work with multiple cores at the same time. Meanwhile the packages pbdR, multicore y etc are not available for the version of RStudio I'm using (3.4.4).
2. I'm thinking to optimize the for loop in order to use the parallel code more efficient, but have no idea how to do it.

So, finally, my question: 
Any ideas how to optimize the for loop and after how to parallelize it, in plan (maybe) how to split it or what to do for it to be executed with 4 cores at the same time and save the time, bc its take forever to execute and I need as less as possible (the data frame initial has more than 250 000 rows)? 
I use Windows virtual machine with 4 cores

Thanks for the help, in advance!

PS. it's precise to have the result added by rows in a final data frame

Comment: This is going to be tough to answer directly without some reproducible data. It seems like what you are trying to accomplish is essentially a complex multi-table "join" and "filter" of several tables. I'd recommend thinking about how you can either: 1. Implement this directly in `SQL` as a set of JOIN statements and sub-queries. 2. If you can fit in your local memory, bring the tables you need back to `R` up front (1 query per table), and then use `data.table` to do the join/filtering in a vectorized manner. _Either way, I would focus on optimizing, not parallelizing at this time._

Comment: @MattSummersgill thnx! Unfortunately I can't use directly sql, everything should be done in r. And yes, I'm trying firstly to optimize the code, bc other way it would be tough to speed up the execution. I found some ways like to vectorize the code, but I'm not that common to me to use apply family and so on, so if you know, maybe, how could I do it, would be fantastic!

Comment: If you do a "SELECT *" on the tables `stock.V_CALCULOS` and  `stock.clasificaciones`, will they take up less than half of your computer's memory? The the thing that is probably slowing you down the most is the communication overhead associated with sending _(by my count)_ 1,632 queries to a database and then sending results back to R, one at a time. This problem should not require a loop, and if you can work with the entire set of data at once (either by doing the joins in `SQL` or in `R`) you should be able to process this several of orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @MattSummersgill aww, now I got you, thanks! The first version was to set the data frame in the R environment, but it appeared to be, that I must all the time take it from from Oracle, that's the shit, and if it's the thing that slows down the process, that I'll try to convince to change the condition to have it once executed from Oracle. Thank you men, this really gave me some inspiration and hope!

Comment: If that's feasible, then your query functions can be replaced with accessor-functions, and my answer will solve another aspect of inefficiency (I think). Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteratively building a `data.frame` row-by-row scales *horribly*. Instead, I suggest creating each iteration's output into a `list` and then bind at the end. I don't have your data, so this is untested. I'm also going to assume that Matt's comment about 1,632 SQL queries is unavoidable (because that's likely a big bottleneck).

Bottom line: your problem areas are likely (1) thousand-plus SQL queries, and (2) iteratively building your results with `rbind`.

This pre-builds all of the iterations within your nested `for` loops.

```
eg <- expand.grid(Year=x, classProduct=d, product=y, classBranch=g, branch=z)
```

Now let's add the `_df` and `_string` variables; I'm using `dplyr` here for the grouping and such, though there are other ways (both base-R and `data.table`):

```
library(dplyr)
eg <- eg %>%
  group_by(classProduct, product) %>%
  mutate(
    prod_string = hijos_string(con, classProduct[1], product[1]),
    product_df = paste(product, prod_string[1], sep=",")
  ) %>%
  group_by(classBranch, branch) %>%
  mutate(
    branch_string = hijos_string(con, classProduct[1], branch[1]),
    branch_df = paste(branch, branch_string[1], sep=",")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This is still inefficient by Matt's comment, but far less inefficient from the iteratively-adding-rows perspective:

```
lst <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(eg)), function(i) {
  consulta <- sprintf("select * from stock.V_CALCULOS where  CODNIV1 = 9 and CODNIV2 = %d and CODNIV4 = %d and CODNIV3 in (%s) and CODNIV5 in (%s) order by codniv1, codniv2, codniv3, codniv4, codniv5, codlugar, codunidad, anyo",
                      eg$classProduct[i], eg$classBranch[i], eg$product_df[i], eg$branch_df[i])
  resuni <- dbSendQuery(con, consulta)
  datos_inversion <- fetch(resuni, n=-1)
  dbClearResult(resuni)
  resultado(datos_inversion, eg$classProduct[i], eg$classBranch[i], eg$year[i], eg$product[i],
            eg$branch[i], eg$prod_string[i], eg$branch_string[i])
})
dat <- do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Again, I don't know if this'll work perfectly, but the rationale is sound and (I think) relatively straight-forward.

Comment: thank you! idk why, at least, don´t get it, but it´s giving an error `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    branch_string = hijos_string(con, classProduct[1], branch[1])
    branch_df"
>   ) %>%
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
>   ungroup()
Error in UseMethod("ungroup") : 
  no applicable method for 'ungroup' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: Missed a comma, check again.

Comment: thank you, i´m sorry to be the pain in the ass, since i´m a sup new r user, but now it´s giving the new error `Error in grep("row[_.]names", names(rs), value = TRUE) : 
  object 'rs' not found` I was discovering what´s `grep`, and where´s it in the code, but didn´t find the relation, or maybe didn´t understand it. And since it´s working with `pattern`, which is not in the code as well, maybe there´s smth i´m missing, don´t see?

Comment: Nope, that's not me. I [googled the command that failed](https://www.google.com/search?q=grep%28%22row%5B_.%5Dnames%22%2C+names%28rs%29%2C+value+%3D+TRUE%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) and the first return (for me) is in [`sqldf`](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/blob/master/R/sqldf.R#L435). I don't see you using `sqldf` in either of your `hijos*` functions, so I wouldn't know where to begin.